# How to read EBNF grammar rules from a file?

Tags: java, context-free-grammar, ebnf

I think my question is very stupid but I didn't find an answer to my problem yet.
I have a file .txt with EBNF grammar rules, and I want to read them in such a way to encode them in a graph. Is there an algorithm that can understand the notation of the grammar, i.e. the semantic meaning of the symbols? For example, say I have a rule like that: 
    `A := (b (c | d)*)+` .
How can I efficiently read that rule understanding the precedences?

Comment: Ahahahah super nice comment. You really think you're funny and ironic, don't you? I do think so a lot :) .

Comment: Not funny, just correct.

Comment: Ok so if you're not ironic I think that you did a mistake: the URL "google.com" corresponds to the Google search engine not to the Stack Overflow one. So you're not even correct. Try again

Comment: Ok so let's just answer you the last time and then I'll definitely stop to keep on this useless and infantile discussion, even because you should know better than me that comments are made for adding value to a discussion not to be just as arrogant and insolent as you are. Looking at your profile I can deduce that you're an excellent programmer, bravo! The problem is that this cannot let you spread arrogance and insults just because you have 27k of follower in a website, don't you think?

Comment: Also, have you ever asked yourself why you spent so much time on a computer answering questions to people instead to make a real life? Look, outside there are other poor and ugly people with whom you can exchange emotions and opinions!! Give it a try

Comment: Anyway, my question was wrong posed. In fact, I didn't want to be resent to a question where the website of ANTLR is there, because I looked at this website hundred times in this week and to other parsing tools or parser generator tools. But I hoped to have an answer more specific on a part of the parser, the part in which it understands the syntax of an EBNF grammar and it doesn't do any other thing. I'll look at the source code of ANTLR or other tools even if it was my last choice. Or maybe I'll find a person nicer than you.